# AJAX filling table input array fields

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, html-table

I have a form which contains a table with input fields. I want to the select input fields of the second  to be updated based on the selected value of first 
using AJAX

```
<td><select class='form-control select2' id='name[]' name='name[]' onchange="getSize(this);">
                    <option> select　</option>
                    
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM m_table ORDER BY 1 ASC";
                $res = pg_query($conn,$sql);
                $num_row = pg_num_rows($res);
                if($num_row > 0)
                        {
                            while ($row=pg_fetch_row($res))
                            {
                                echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.trim($row['0']).'" >'.trim($row['0']).'</OPTION>';
                            }
                        }
                ?>                  
                                                
                </select>
            </td>       
            <td><select class='form-control select2' id='m_size[]' name='m_size[]' >
            <!------------------------------------>             
            
            <!------------------------------------>
                </select>
            </td>
```

How shall I get the value of name[] inside jquery?
How shall I update the value of m_size[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was troubling with the issue. Hope this answer will help someone.

```
function getSize(e){    
    
    var tr = $(e).closest("tr");
    
    var rowindex = tr.index() ; 
    
    var NAME = document.forms[0].elements["name[]"];

    var name = NAME[rowindex].value;
    
    var gsizeOptions = null;

        $.ajax({
                  url:"getSize.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:{name:name},     
                  dataType: 'html',
                  //async: false,             
                  success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    sizeOptions = data; 
       var MSIZE= document.forms[0].elements["m_size[]"];
       $(MSIZE[rowindex]).append(sizeOptions);      
                      }         
                 }); 

    }
```

Comment: Using `async: false` is a horrible practice that should never  ever be used  and has been deprecated by browser vendors. All you need to do is make the append inside the `success` callback

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice. I have edited my answer.